# Marmoset Toolbag or modeling problem

Tags: modifiers, bevel

**The models that I modeled using bevel and boolean in Blender are malfunctioning when I throw them into the Marmoset Toolbag. How can I fix this.**
[image]

Comment: You could always triangulate them before exporting. If you add a triangulate modifier and enable "apply modifiers" in the export, then this is done none-destructively (at least in Blender).

Comment: I didn't know about that, thank you so much.

Comment: I don't know Marmoset toolbag, but most programs will triangulate these concav n-gons differently. Maybe someone who knows it can suggest a better workflow =)

Comment: If I just use it for rendering in marmoset, this modifier solves my problem. But of course, the topology of the model doesn't look like I want.